# Delphi 10.1 - problems with Datetime picker after Creators Update of Windows 10

Tags: windows, delphi, datetime, upgrade, picker

After creators update of Windows 10 (version 1703) we have a problem with misrepresentation of datetime pickers content:

[image: TDateTimePicker VCL component] [image: TfrxDateEdit Control (Fastreports)]

Do you have any workaround for this problem? Enabling runtime themes is not an option for us (it solves the problem with garbled text, but it changes appearance of application too much).

Comment: How do we reproduce this?

Comment: are you using standard Delphi component TDateTimePicker? or JVCL ?

Comment: On the left picture is TDateTimePicker VCL component, on the right is TfrxDateEdit Control (Fastreports dialog).

Answer (score 8):

This is a problem of Windows 10 Creators Update. Here is an answer from Microsoft regarding that problem:

> This only occurs in applications that use the Date Time Picker
>   implemented on COMCTL32 V5. Any application using the COMCTL32 V5 Date
>   Time Picker on RS2 will encounter this problem, including MFC and
>   Windows Forms applications. Unfortunately, there is currently no
>   workaround for the issue when using the COMCTL32 V5 Date Time Picker
>   other than removing the RS2 update, if possible. Affected applications
>   could be updated to use COMCTL32 V6, but this is not a trivial change
>   due to the differences in the control implementations between V5 and
>   V6.

As you may notice, currently the only solution is to enable runtime themes or rollback the Windows update.

Answer (score 1):

I can confirm rolling back to before Creators Update fixes the problem. We use Delphi 5.

Is Microsoft aware of this problem? This is a major problem for a developer with a large installed base.

I tried updating COMCTL32 to V6 through the command prompt, but Windows always undid my work.

Comment: Is this a question or an answer?

Comment: an answer that it happens on other versions of delphi.